# What is the difference between += and regular sum in the following C++ code?

Tags: c++

I have a function that sums a Binary Number.

Ex : a = "1" and b = "0"
Sum = "1"

This is the function and it works:

```
string addBinary(string a, string b)
{
    string s = "";

    int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = b.size() - 1;
    while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1)
    {
        c += i >= 0 ? a[i --] - '0' : 0;
        c += j >= 0 ? b[j --] - '0' : 0;
        s = char(c % 2 + '0') + s;
        c /= 2;
    }

    return s;
}
```

I just replace += like this :

```
string addBinary(string a, string b)
{
    string s = "";

    int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = b.size() - 1;
    while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1)
    {
        c = c + i >= 0 ? (a[i--] - '0') : 0;
        c = c + j >= 0 ? (b[j--] - '0') : 0;
        s = char(c % 2 + '0') + s;
        c /= 2;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Now I enter a = "1" and b = "0" and I get Sum = "0".

Comment: Um, the second version doesn't compile.

Comment: I am sorry mistyped it ..its corrected now

Comment: I think I must have missed where you actually asked a question

Comment: why am I getting 0 when I enter a = 1 and b = 0 in the second function and 1 in the first

Comment: `c = c + (i >= 0 ? (a[i--] - '0') : 0);` Read about operator precedence.

Comment: Use `c += ((i >= 0) ? (a[i --] - '0') : 0);` or `c = c + ((i >= 0) ? (a[i--] - '0') : 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second, you do:

`c + i >= 0`

which means that first you add and then compare.

In the first you do:

`i >= 0`

and then add up the `c`.

It's about operators priority and using the *parentheses*!